# Can I call Type.GetMethod() for private method on mocked class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have a private method in aspx.cs class. I want to unit test it. I know I should not unit test private methods but I need it for now.

SomeClass.aspx.cs

```
public partial class SomeClass : OtherClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        //some code
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = GetDataTable();
        var s = "";
        foreach(var dataRow in dataTable.Rows){
            s = MyPrivateMethod(dataRow);
        }
    }
    private string MyPrivateMethod(DataRow dr)
    {
        //method implementation
    }
}
```

Unit test

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestForPrivateMethod()
{
    Type type = typeof(Mock<SomeClass>); 

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

//Did this just for checking. It consists of names of MOQ methods and not an actual SomeClass methods
var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(x=>x.Name);

//This throws exception saying there are no elements in sequece. That's because it doesn't have any elements matching MyPrivateMethod()
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
.Where(x => x.Name == "MyPrivateMethod" && x.IsPrivate)
.First();

DataTable table = CreateTable();
var row = CreateRows();

var result = (string)method.Invoke(instance, new object[] { row });

Assert.AreEqual(result, string.Empty);
```

}

I can not call .Setup() because method I am trying to test in private.
Can I use MOQ on a class inside which there is a private method to test?

Comment: Why don't you make it `protected` and use [`Moq.Protected`](https://riptutorial.com/moq/example/27613/mocking-protected-members)?

Comment: Why are you mocking at all? If the point is to test `SomeClass`, you shouldn't be mocking `SomeClass`... the point of mocking something is to make its implementation irrelevant.

Comment: Why are you mocking the class you're trying to test? Typically you only mock _dependencies_.

Comment: @DStanley I am mocking this class because if I do Activator.CreateInstance(SomeClass) directly, I'll get an error. When SomeClass is created, other classes are created. During testing, I don't have data to create that other classes. Should I use Moq for these other classes? if so, how? I'm creating class A and class B inside SomeClass

Comment: You could reorganize the class so that instances of `A` and `B` are _injected_ rather than _created_, and then mock _them_, but that may be the wrong approach just to unit test a private method. Could you put the methods in some other class (or a "helper" library") and unit test it from there?

Comment: Or make `MyPrivateMethod` `static` so that you can call it without creating an instance of the page (assuming it doesn't use any instance members).

Comment: @DStanley that sounds good but it's much more complicated code than I tried to show. Anyway, thanks for letting me know about the options